# Why can't babel find its helper functions when compiling style changes with webpack in watch mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-3

Having some issues with babel and webpack. 
I'm not sure what introduced this issue, Its been intermittent, happened a few days ago then went away after hours of trying to debug. I'm not sure what fixed it then.

[webpack.config](https://gist.github.com/arlofeirman/3186b56b88003c0c93e8149199e42a2a) --- [relevant parts of package.json](https://gist.github.com/arlofeirman/1d69b70de22ada9ca4bcce987db95018)

The project is a multi-page jQuery and Flask app that is being moved to React. We are also using `react-bootstrap`.

**The issue is:**

- When I make a change in a sass or css file
- After webpack compiles
- Babel can't find some of its helper functions. Either the paths cannot
  be resolved, or the wrong paths are being inserted.
- This only happens when webpack is running in watch mode. Restarting webpack will make the errors go away.
- The errors come back once I start watch mode again and make a change to any of my sass or css.

Some of the errors I've been getting on page load after compiling style changes:

**1.**

In console:`Uncaught TypeError: dP.f is not a function`

File in chrome inspector, `_hide.js`

```
var dP = require('./_object-dp');
var createDesc = require('./_property-desc');
module.exports = require('./_descriptors') ? function (object, key, value) {
  return dP.f(object, key, createDesc(1, value));
} : function (object, key, value) {
  object[key] = value;
  return object;
};

// WEBPACK FOOTER
// ./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_hide.js
// module id = 136
// module chunks = 17
```

**2.**

Error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_babel_runtime_helpers_inherits___default.a is not a function`

File in chrome inspector, `PanelGroup.js` - from `react-bootstrap` relevant parts.

```
import _inherits from 'babel-runtime/helpers/inherits';

var PanelGroup = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(PanelGroup, _React$Component);
```

**3.**

Error in console: `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_babel_runtime_helpers_possibleConstructorReturn___default.a is not a function`

File in chrome inspector, `Collapse.js` - from `react-bootstrap` relevant parts.

`import _possibleConstructorReturn from 'babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn';`

**UPDATE:**

`rm -rf node_modules` does not help. Making any change to the JS entry file for the page will cause webpack to recompile and the error to go away.